# Is there a standard name for testing the number of tests, or other calculated parameters?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, terminology

This is a general question about testing, independent of language.

One method I often use when writing tests, which I've never heard of before although I surely didn't invent it, is the following:

Suppose that I'm testing something multiple times, e.g. in a loop; e.g., it could be artificially generated test data. E.g., it might be calling a func(...) which returns some data containing a list/vector/array etc. etc. of results.

I have at the start of the test something like

`int total_size = 0`

...and with each calculated result:

`data = func(...)`

`do_some_test(data)`

`total_size = total_size + data.size()`

Then, finally at the end of the test, I'll do

`TEST_THAT(total_size == 10000)`

...or whatever the value is. Of course, it might not be size that I test; it could use any discrete or integer-valued property of the data objects.

So, this could be regarded as a very weak kind of integer-valued hash of test data, input and/or output, although human-readable.

**There are at least four reasons to do this:**

(a) Check that we are actually testing something; it's all too easy to have bugs in test code which mean that we're not testing anything, or as much as we thought.

(b) If something changes unexpectedly, due to the algorithms or tests, even if the tests still pass, then we have a chance of spotting that it changed.

(c) Although it could give a false sense of security, it's always nice to see that a test has run through 1000 times, or tested 5000 things, etc. etc. rather than just 5, say. If people ask you how well tested something is, you can immediately say *"it has been tested on 2000 objects, of total size 10000"*, or similar.

(d) If running the same code on multiple platforms or compilers, it helps to find differences between them.

So, my questions (sorry, two rather than one!):

**(1) Is this a standard method with a well-known name?**

**(2) Assuming it is well known, is this regarded as good practice (if done sensibly, of course?)**

Comment: This isn't a unit test. This is more of some strange "burn in" test to shake out bugs. Normally you'd do that as part of a "fuzzer" pass, not one where you do the same thing N times. When fuzzing you put in deliberately bad data, or data which is right at the limit of what should be accepted, either numerically or size-wise, etc.

Comment: Yes, this isn't a unit test, but it would usually be put inside a unit test. Thanks for your comment, but I don't see any similarity with burn-in tests. It's not so much about finding bugs, as about catching unintended changes, and also testing the test: I saw a system once which had been apparently running and passing a suite of tests for a long time, but due to a bug in the test code was not actually testing anything. Also, I'm not necessarily doing the same thing N times.

Comment: You generally want your unit tests to be fairly quick to run so that people *do* run them. A more aggressive version of this for pre-deployment screening is a useful tool, but it is also a different tool. A fuzzer will really lay into your code, it'll create millions of entries where in production you're expecting only thousands. It will rapidly create and delete entries to shake out timing bugs. It will perform as many updates per second as it can get away with to see if something shakes loose. It's there to explore limits and find faults, not test that function X does thing Y.

Comment: Consider that more of a "deliberately hostile integration smoke test".

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of `func()` and `data`?

Comment: Many examples, e.g. if func(...) takes some input data and outputs something like, e.g., a string, then data.size() could just be the length of the string; but maybe your unit tests don't check the exact string (maybe too long/tedious to store them), but only look for substrings, etc. etc. So if you test that the total length is, e.g., 110231, then, not ONLY does it make it less likely that changes to the codebase elsewhere affecting it will go unnoticed, but ALSO it gives you a rough idea how much testing there actually is (and it's easy to copy/paste/update 110231 when it DOES change).